# couchdb GET /_stats response interpretation

Tags: couchdb

So we've been trying to make sense of the _stats that couchdb seems to return if you make a GET call to /_stats. The problem is that the units for these entities is not very well defined. For example, this is an example of what's returned for httpd.requests:

```
"httpd": {
  "requests": {
    "description": "number of HTTP requests",
    "current": 191458567.0,
    "sum": 191458567.0,
    "mean": 71.150999999999996248,
    "stddev": 102.38500000000000512,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 1197
  }
}
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows what each of these fields represent. For example, what is the difference between "current" and "sum"? We're getting the same values for these in all the stats. Shouldn't "sum" be greater than "current"? Or, what time interval is the "mean" or "stddev" over? Is it per second? Is it since the beginning of time? Does anyone know of a reference for interpreting these stats? The [couchdb docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/common.html) is not very helpful.

Comment: You might want to get a look into [this](http://gws.github.io/munin-plugin-couchdb/guide-to-couchdb-monitoring.html) wich give more details on these values.

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Runtime_Statistics) says:

> Each metric is aggregated over four periods time. In the default
>   output of /_stats the period of time is since CouchDB was started.
>   [...] aggregate values are calculated on a per-second basis

You can alternatively request for the last 1, 5 or 15 minutes (instead of the time since CouchDB was started), e.g. the number of HTTP requests in the last minute:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/_stats/httpd/requests?range=60
```

I'm interpreting the result as follows:

- **current**: number of HTTP requests (since CouchDB was started)
- **sum**: is not documented, but it seems to equal current in any case
- **mean**: arithmetic mean value of HTTP requests per second
- **stddev**: standard deviation of mean
- **max** and **min**: the respective extremes of HTTP requests per second

I believe that *sum* is never greater than *current*, I could not find its purpose in the documentation.